# How std::map maps a pair as a key to its value without a comparison function

Tags: c++, dictionary, data-structures, std, keyvaluepair

If we use a structure or a class as a key then a comparison function is required to place the values in the tree but if a pair is used as a key then how the map data structure place the values in the tree. I.e. there has to be something to compare the keys and store them in to a tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default comparison function for [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) using the Key type for the arguments. `std::less` just calls the `<` operator on its arguments, [which is defined for `std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) (it compares `first` and `second` lexicographically, using their `operator<`).

Comment: Thanks was lookin for this explanation.